# Binomial Number

Tags: inequality

Please give me feedback on my answer to this question.

> Question:

$\binom{2\cdot2^{1000000}}{2^{1000000}}>2^{2\cdot2^{1000000}}$ .

> Answer:

True. Let $2^{1000000}=x.$ Then $\binom{2\cdot2^{1000000}}{2^{1000000}}=\binom{2x}{x}$  and $2^{2\cdot2^{1000000}}=2^{x}.$ Assume $x=2$ , then $\binom{2x}{x}=\binom{4}{2}=6>2^{x}=4.$

Thus, $\binom{2\cdot2^{1000000}}{2^{1000000}}>2^{2\cdot2^{1000000}}.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=2^{1000000}$. The question seems to be whether $\binom{2n}{n}$ is greater than $2^{2n}$.

Perhaps the following is known to you: it is a consequence of the Binomial Theorem, but can be proved in other ways:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=2^{2n}.\tag{1}$$
So the sum of **all** the binomial coefficients $\binom{2n}{k}$ is equal to $2^{2n}$. It follows that the **particular** binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$, which is part of the sum (1), must be less than $2^{2n}$.

**Remark:** In your answer, you write that $2^{2\cdot 1000000}=2^x$. However, you defined $x$ to be $2^{1000000}$, so $2^{2\cdot 1000000}=2^{2x}$.

It is in fact true that $\binom{2x}{x}\gt 2^x$ if $x\gt 1$. The computation you made is consistent with that fact, but is not enough for a proof.